# Using javascript I want to change the size of images which are in particular div tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

In an HTML document there are few div tags with ids DIV1, DIV2
In DIV1 there are 2 images. in DIV2 there is only a single image. Using javascript I want to change the size of images which are in DIV1 to 100px. How can I specify images which are in that particular div tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that those are `id`s:

```
#div1 img {
    width: 100px;
]
```

Or, if you prefer (for some reason, though you *should use CSS* for this), you can use JavaScript:

```
var div1Images document.getElementById('div1').getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0, len = div1Images; i < len; i++){
     div1Images[i].style.width = '100px';
}
```

The reason I set only *one* dimension (`width`) is that this way the image's `height` will be automatically adjusted to fit maintain the natural aspect-ratio.

Comment: @Kevin: thanks! I've offered a JavaScript solution too, but CSS is quite capable of achieving this aim.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.div1 img')
```

This will give you a `NodeList` object of all of the `img` elements in `<div class=div`>` (obviously change as needed).  You can iterate over it like a normal array and update the element widths to whatever you want .. even 100px!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery its should be as simple as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
 //select images and adjust height & width however you want, or use just width to scale proportionately  
   $('#div1 img').width('100px');
   $('#div1 img').height('100px');
});
```

Here's a jfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/t9pUL/4/

However, I agree with David Thomas that you should probably use css for this unless you have a real reason to use javascript.

Comment: A downvote, any reason other than my suggesting jQuery over plain js?